# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3props.navigation.state.params')

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to build a chat app with react-native expo and  I get this error in Inbox page I also put my chat page(it is what i am trying to navigate)
Please help me! 
I put my dashboard screen also 
I dont have route.js file.

"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3props.navigation.state.params')"

```
        export default class  GelenKutusu extends React.Component {
            state={
                userList:[]
            }
            componentWillMount(){
                firebase.database().ref().child('users').once('value',(snap)=>{
                    let userList=[]
                    snap.forEach((user)=>{
                        const {first_name,profile_picture,uid}=user.val()
                        userList.push({first_name,profile_picture,uid})
                })
                this.setState({userList})
            })
        }
            render() {
              return (
                              <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',width:width-40,paddingBottom:10}}>
                            <Text style={{color:'grey',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18}}>Inbox</Text>
                        </View>
                        <FlatList
                        data={this.state.userList}
                        keyExtractor={(item,index)=>item.first_name}
                        renderItem={({item})=>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat',{user:this.props.navigation.state.params.user, profile:item})} >
                            <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'transparent', flexDirection: 'row', padding:5, width:width}}>
                           <Image style={{height:40, width:40,borderRadius:20}}
                              source={{ uri: item.profile_picture  }} />
                              <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                                 <Text style={{color:'grey', fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.first_name}</Text>
                              </View>
                              </View>
                              <View style={{width:width, height:1,backgroundColor:'darkgrey'}} />
                              </TouchableOpacity>
                        } />
                    </View>
                );
            }
        } 


Here is chat.js


    export default class chat extends Component{
        state={
            messages:[],
            user:this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
            profile:this.props.navigation.state.params.profile
        }
        componentWillMount(){
            const {user,profile}=this.state
            this.chatID= user.uid > profile.uid? user.uid+'-'+profile.uid:profile.uid+'-'+user.uid
            this.watchChat()
        }
        watchChat=()=>{        firebase.database().ref('messages').child(this.chatID).on('value',snap=>{
                let messages=[]
                snap.forEach(messages=>{
                    messages.push(messages.val())
                })
                messages.reverse()
                this.setState({messages})
            })
        }
        onSend=(messages)=>{
            const {user,profile}=this.state
            relationMessage={}    firebase.database().ref('messages').child(this.chatID).push({...message[0],createdAt:new Date().getTime(),
            })
        }
        render(){
            const {user,profile}=this.state
            const avatar = user.profile_picture
            return(
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                  <GiftedChat
                    messages={this.state.messages}
                    user={{_id:user.uid,avatar}}
                    onSend={this.onSend()}
                    />
                    </View>
            )
        }
    }




Here is my Dashboard.js screen 


class  DashboardScreen extends Component {

    render(){
        return (

          <NavigationContainer> 

          <Stack.Navigator
         screenOptions={{
           gestureEnabled: true,
           gestureDirection: "horizontal",

           // transitionSpec: {
             // open: config,
             // close: closeConfig
             // }
         }}
         headerMode="float"
         animmation="fade" >
           <Stack.Screen options={{
          headerRight: () => (

            <Ionicons name="ios-search" size={38}  
            style={{ margin: 5, padding: 5}}
            onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
            />

          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Ionicons name="ios-add" size={48}  
            style={{ margin: 5, padding: 5}}
            onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
            />
          ),
        }} name = "                 "
           component={MyTabs} />
           <Stack.Screen  name="Header" component={MyTabsTop}  />
         </Stack.Navigator>

            </NavigationContainer>

        );
    }
}

export default DashboardScreen;

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
        let iconName;

        if (route.name === 'Home') {
          iconName ='ios-home'
        } 
        else if (route.name === 'Bildirimler') {
          iconName ='ios-notifications'
        }
        else if (route.name === 'GelenKutusu') {
          iconName ='ios-chatboxes'
        }
        else if (route.name === 'Profil') {
          iconName ='ios-contact'
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
      }
    })} >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Bildirimler" component={Bildirimler} />
      <Tab.Screen name="GelenKutusu" component={GelenKutusu} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profil" component={Profil} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MyTabsTop() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Profil}
          options={{ title: 'My home' }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
```

This is context.

Comment: Are you using navigation? If so please share your navigation code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```
onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat',{user:this.props.navigation.state.params.user, profile:item})}
```

You are passing a param which you are getting from another component.

First get your params in render like this:

```
 render() {
    /Read the params from the navigation state */
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const user= params ? params.user: null;
```

Here you will get the user param and use in your navigation

```
       onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat',{user:user, profile:item})}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for helping me but its still the same.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to the Chat screen if you are not passing params and can you post your navigation and from the screen where you are passing params

Comment: No i am not able to navigate chat screen. i edit the questions you can see my chat screen now.

Comment: You had not posted your navigation page, we need a page where you had defined routes

Comment: I havent defined routes maybe it is the problem.I put dashboard.js.Those are  the only routes that i define. I dont have knowledge to  build by my own. I am taking chat part from some video login part from another video. I cant learn by my own there is no react-native source in my language.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem first you need to create a routes page by which you can navigate among them, how many screens do you have in your project

Comment: Loading,Dashboard,Home,Profile,inbox,login. These all. It was ok before i create chat.js but i cant navigate to chat screen i donw even know it s workin very well. Can you help me in this please.

Comment: sure will do, once check this docs https://blog.logrocket.com/navigating-react-native-apps-using-react-navigation/

Comment: I read this blog. I put my app.js also in my new questions can u check it please.